# Display an image from database after selecting input

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to display an image from my database after selecting from input using php  I tried to use a function  when I choose a the image name it will display 
but nothing happend and when I don't use the function all images appear randomly
need help and sorry for my bad English
this  is my code

#### PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "ont";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$query = "SELECT nom FROM `equipement`";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$options = "";

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    echo $options;
    $options = $options."<option>$row1[0]</option>";
}

function ajout()
{
    $sqlimage  = "SELECT image FROM equipement";
    $imageresult1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlimage);
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($imageresult1))
    {
        $image = $rows['image'];
        echo "<img src='$image' >";
        echo "<br>";
    } 
}
?>
```

#### HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="room.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select name="image_name">
        <?php echo $options;?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `$conn` is not defined in `ajout`. You need to learn about variables scope.

Answer (score 0):

As u_mulder said that you have to define `$con` as argument in function `ajout` than you have to call it in your php script where you need it.

```
<?php 
   //previous code
 function ajout($connection)
{
   $sqlimage  = "SELECT image FROM equipement ";
   $imageresult1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sqlimage);
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($imageresult1))
   {
    $image = $rows['image'];
    echo "<img src='$image' >";
    echo "<br>"; 
   } 
}
ajout($con) ;
?>
```

Solution for your question in comment is

```
<form action="yourphpfile.php" method="POST">
<select name="image_name" >
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="rose">Rose</option>
    <option value="lily">Lily</option>
    <option value="lotus">Lotus</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now user click on button &  your php file will execute where you can get value like `$user_flower_name = $_POST['image_name']` & user in your sql query to find out.

Remember `$_POST['image_name']` will return `option` tag's value not innerText between them.

Comment: i did that  but the image display without pressing the button can you help me modify  the query i want to select a name of an image from my data base then display it using a selecting input and thanks

Comment: you want  image's name from user then search in database & show it .

Comment: i have a select input where the name of all my images are there . when i choose a name from my input i want it to show

Comment: is there a way to return innerText cause i dont have values in my option see my html code and thanks

Comment: you can add value as innerText .

Comment: i am confuse you are showing `option` from database or you choosing value of option from html than match with table.